# How can I change VS Code's limits on number of search results and multiple cursors for the Select All Occurrences of Find Match command?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want to find and replace using regex in the same file. Actually, it's a huge file.

I want to increase the results to consider higher or all occurrences.

in the settings:

```
"search.maxResults":
```

not helpful because I want to increase the results for the search in the same file.

if there is no official way, I will be happy if there is an extension to do it.

I use (control + shift + l) to highlight all occurrences then move the cursor some spaces and change all the occurrences. the highlighting stuff is only for 19999. it is not just replace

Answer (score 2):

For the `Select All Occurrences of Find Match`, you need to increase the value of the `editor.multiCursorLimit`. The default value is 10,000.

I just did a simple test with 20k "abc" in a file, and replaced all with "def". Even thought the widget said "19999+", it replaced all instances. I'd suggest you just try it if you haven't already. I think it will work just the way you want it to. Though it won't highlight any more matches than specified by the `search.maxResults` setting unless you set it to `null` to allow for unlimited matches.

Some related issue tickets- some historical, some still open:

- [Find widget only highlights the first 19999/20000 matches
  #496](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/496)
- ["Select all occurrences of current selection"can not select the contents of more than 1000 rows. #5887](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5887)
- [search.maxResults does not affect how many results are found/highlighted #169017](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/169017)